# Andromeda paradox confusion

Tags: time

In the Andromeda paradox if I walk past you we have different ideas of what's happening now on Andromeda, does this lead to two versions of Andromeda? Do the Andromedeans know what they are doing in their frame, we just apply differing coordinates?

Comment: What do you mean by "versions"? I think you might have misinterpreted the paradox.

Comment: As in like if I move a different version of andromeda exists for you

Comment: Try switching the roles of Earth and Andromeda. Do you know what you're doing in your frame?

Comment: Nmmm, I'm trying to figure this out cus I guess I'm wrong about a of this. So, in relativity is anything changed for our consciousness relative to each other

Comment: Actually, SR provides just the right changes of coordinates so that there is only 1 Andromeda, even if it appears different in different coordinate systems. That's the whole point. 2 different observers should be able to change to the coordinate frame of Andromeda and find the same Andromeda there.

Comment: Just walk backwards. Problem solved. This andromeda paradox again? Theres better things to occupy your time and mind with. Sorry, bud, this one has always bugged me. It's becoming another "the chicken or the egg" in annoyance level for me. What if one of them stepped in gum? If rain fell on one could the other feel the warmth of a cold flame? Et al

Comment: The strange case of the missing seed. Solved 1843 by Rudolf Karamini.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not lead to two different versions of Andromeda. Think about it. There are billions of people of Earth all moving in different directions and speeds- there would need to be billions of different versions of Andromeda if your interpretation held.

If ever you are confused by Special Relativity, you might want to to remember that its key principle is that all inertial motion is relative, and therefore all of the relativistic effects of SR apply symmetrically between different frames. That means that you are moving at all kinds of speeds relative to different frames. Do you, then, feel time dilated, length contracted, split into multiple versions etc as a consequence of your motion relative to other frames? Of course not, so why do you suppose those effects have a different impact on Andromeda?

Comment: But if I move my concept of now changes dramatically, but what if the people on Andromeda aren't doing that which I consider now, isn't that two versions

Comment: Or at the very least andromeda flies backwards and forwards in time

Comment: No! There is only one version. Consider someone stationary relative to us on Andromeda for whom now is the same as our now, ie 12th March 2023. There might be someone walking on Andromeda in whose frame of reference now is next August. But we haven't reached next August yet. We don't currently exist in next August. It is like asking what is happening in New York next year. The answer is nothing yet because New York hasn't reached next year yet.

Comment: There are not two versions of New York, one here now and one existing next year. There is one New York moving forward in time.

Comment: So you're completely against block time or can we think like this even if its true.